# How to stop CHROME from reloading all tabs when we restart/open the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

There is a feature in **SLIMJET**, which offers an option to ***not load background tabs at startup***. In which tabs are shown in the tab strip but not loaded until you click on it. This feature is also available in **FIREFOX** also by default.

Chrome Version : **56.0.2924.87**

I have read another post here saying

> To actually disable:, type in your address bar:  **chrome://flags**, then
>   disable this flag: **#automatic-tab-discarding** (Turn it to 'Disabled'
>   from 'Default')

But this thing is also not working in Chrome 56.0.2924.87

**So please kindly enlighten me.**

Answer (score 5):

Automatic-tab-discarding is only for those tabs that have been discarded (content deleted) due to chrome's lack of RAM (PC in which Chrome is running lack of free RAM actually). The behavior with discarded tabs is to reload them only when you click on them hence not consuming RAM until you're actually  interested in seeing them. Chrome will only discard tabs when it's short of RAM.

What you should do to solve your problem (which is a different thing ) is :

1. Type: about:flags
2. Locate the flags Offline Auto-Reload Mode  and Only Auto-Reload Visible Tabs
3. Select disable and enable respectively

[image: chrome flags - Auto-Reload]

Comment: Can not see such a flag anymore. Looks like it have been removed, right?

Comment: @FreeLightman it seems like it.