# How to prevent wifi login screen from overwriting tabs in a browser

Tags: wireless-networking, browser, safari

I'm sure others have faced this frustrating issue in the past.

Say you have a dozen tabs open in a browser and you are at a hotel or cafe attempting to use their wifi. You select the wifi ID and all of a sudden, the wifi login screen populates **all** of your tabs, with no option to go back to the previous website. The content in those tabs has been lost, forever.

How does one prevent this from happening?

Comment: It seems it was addressed here: http://superuser.com/questions/703800/how-to-avoiding-losing-your-current-browsers-websites-when-being-redirected-by-w?rq=1

Comment: You can flag to close as a duplicate (which I have done).